# MVC Change datetype in view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, date

i want to change that datetype to month/year. 
how can i do it ?

[image: Date format image]

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Month { get; set; }

<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Month, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
     <div class="col-sm-9 input-group date">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Month, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-circle " } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Month, "", new { @class = "text-danger " })
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using a front end framework or component to generate the markup for your date selector. You'll probably need to find out what that is and look in the documentation for it in order to change the format.

Comment: Since the field in the model which it is binding to is a `DateTime` then entering only month and year without a day will result in an error. You'd have to write some extra code to add a default day (e.g. 01) to the string before you submit the form. Or maybe you're better not using a DateTime here...it depends what the final information you want to store is. It might even be better as two separate "month" and "year" fields implemented as dropdown lists. Again it depends what you actually need to store in your backend.

Comment: @Luke it looks like a standard [HTML5 date control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) to me (as rendered by Chrome, other browsers may render it differently e.g. Firefox, Edge). Since the model field is a DateTime, that Razor code will render an `<input type="date` element into the markup, which (modern) browsers will attach a datepicker to. There's no extra component involved. There's also AFAIK no way to turn it into a month/year only control, it can only handle day, month and year combined.